# Meteor - iterating through FS.Collection

Tags: node.js, meteor

I'm having serious troubles iterating through an FS.Collection object...

I'm uploading and storing files using GridFS. I have a function (showAllFiles) as follows:

```
vm.showAllFiles = function(){
    console.log("showAllFiles");

    FS.Utility.each(vm.AllFiles, function(fileObj) {
    //also tried: vm.AllFiles.forEach(function(fileObj){
      console.log(fileObj);
    });
}
```

where:

```
var vm = this;
var store = new FS.Store.GridFS("allFiles");
vm.AllFiles = new FS.Collection("allFiles", {stores: [store]});

$reactive(this).attach($scope);
vm.AllFiles = this.subscribe('AllFiles');
```

But unfortunately I get this error in the browser's console:

[image]

Here's the server side:

```
var store = new FS.Store.GridFS("allFiles", {
  mongoUrl: 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:3001/meteor/'
});
var AllFiles = new FS.Collection("allFiles", {
  stores: [store]
});

Meteor.publish('AllFiles', function () {
  var obj=AllFiles.find();
  return obj;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you're overriding your collection name with the subscription. This is creating a disturbance in the force:

```
vm.AllFiles = new FS.Collection("allFiles", {stores: [store]});
...
vm.AllFiles = this.subscribe('AllFiles');
```

Let's change the second one to:

```
vm.AllFilesSub = this.subscribe('AllFiles');
```

To show all the documents in a collection we `.find()` on the collection to create a cursor and then iterate over that:

```
vm.AllFiles.find().forEach(function(doc){console.log(doc)});
```